# Click event without selectionchange or mouse move

Tags: javascript

I have a table where click on the row will trigger navigation to another page. The issue is that when user tries to select some text from the row (e.g. to copy it later to the clipboard) `click` event is still fired by the browser.

Same unwanted `click` happens if there is already some text selected and used clicks it just to remove selection.

Is there is an easy way to distinquish "pure" click from clicks with mouse move or where selection has changed?

PS. By easy I mean a way without also listening for mouse `move` and/or `selectionchange` evenets.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to check if there was any selection made before the click handling with the help of the Selection API:

```
const selection = window.getSelection();

// Check that no selection was made
if (selection.isCollapsed) {
  // Navigate to another page here
}
```

Comment: Even works for the use case of clicking on the selection to deselect it! (At least in Chrome on Windows)